# Composer REST Server Localhost:3000 refused to connect

Tags: rest, localhost, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've created a business network on Hyperledger Composer and tested it out on  Composer playground and it works great. I could add participants, add assets, perform transactions etc. I tried to generate a bespoke rest API for the business network using the guide available at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial and it worked great as well.

The output for the command `composer-rest-server --card admin@my-network` is this:

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Discovering the Returning Transactions..
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Added schemas for all types to Loopback
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
```

It's a good output but when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000` it fails with error `This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.`

I also generated a skeleton Angular application using the same guide and when I run `npm start` it returns a positive `NG Live Development Server is running on http://0.0.0.0:4200`which also fails with `localhost refused to connect.`

I'm using an Azure Ubuntu 18.04 to build and run the network. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your port blocking service like firewall and try again. Hope it helpfull